# Mockito.when thenReturn based on input parameter

Tags: java, unit-testing, testing, mockito

I have some code with encryption. In tests, I want to analyze the encrypted packet, decrypt and return back a result. What I want is something like:

```
Mockito.when(myClient.sendMessage(someEncryptedRandomMessage)).thenReturn(encrypt(decryptAndAnalyze(someEncryptedRandomMessage)));
```

How I can realize it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is `thenAnswer` method which can access passed parameters. Assuming that your `someEncryptedRandomMessage` is `String` it will look like this

```java
Mockito.when(myClient.sendMessage(someEncryptedRandomMessage))
       .thenAnswer(inv -> encrypt(decryptAndAnalyze(inv.getArgumentAt(0, String.class))));
```